# How to find close/common values among two 2D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have 2 numpy arrays containing unique BGR values, like:

`arr1 = np.array([[159, 102, 66], [151, 92, 58], [155, 96, 62]])`

`arr2 = np.array([[161, 104, 68], [159, 102, 66], [159, 101, 67]])`

I want to find common values among those arrays independent of order, for this example I am interested in finding the common values and number of common values, like: `[[159, 102, 66]]` and the number of elements as `1`.

Lastly, I want to know if there is a way to do this operation with close values, like I want to find `[159, 101, 67]` along with `[[159, 102, 66]]` from `arr2`, since it's very close to `[159, 102, 66]` from `arr1`. It doesn't matter which value I get (whether from `arr1` or `arr2`) when there are close values, because I am mainly intrested in number of common/close values for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) you can use broadcasting:

```
thresh = 1

out = (abs(arr1[:,None]-arr2)<=thresh).all(axis=-1)
```

Output:

```
# arr2: row0    row1   row2      # arr1:
array([[False,  True,  True],    # row0
       [False, False, False],    # row1
       [False, False, False]])   # row2
```

You can then get the rows for each array using:

```
arr1[out.any(axis=1)]
# array([[159, 102,  66]])


arr2[out.any(axis=0)]
# array([[159, 102,  66],
#        [159, 101,  67]])
```

Comment: Can you add more detailed explanations for index and axis selections?

Comment: @MertCanBasut what is unclear to you? The broadcasting compares each pair of rows, which we then reduce to a single boolean with `all`, so you have as many rows as there are rows in `arr1` and as many columns as there are rows in `arr2`.

Comment: Can it be implemented to multiple arrays, like if I want to compare 3 arrays and find common values among all of them?

Comment: @Mert you can do it by pairs yes, but this will quickly become expensive, the more arrays the more combinations

Answer (score 1):

You might find common sub-arrays using built-in set arithemtic however you need to convert sub-arrays into hashable type(s) first, I would use `tuple` following way

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[159, 102, 66], [151, 92, 58], [155, 96, 62]])
arr2 = np.array([[161, 104, 68], [159, 102, 66], [159, 101, 67]])
set1 = set(map(tuple,arr1))
set2 = set(map(tuple,arr2))
common = set1.intersection(set2)
print(common)
```

output

```
{(159, 102, 66)} # set holding single tuple
```